# how to pass event data between two modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two separate angular modules in a website , and i want to do event handling between the modules . I cannot have a common parent module or controller between them as one of them is a header template , and their is a common body html file in which partials are included according to the page (header is constant in that) . In short i have technical boundations in doing that . 
Here is a short brief about my situation: 
i have a service defined , which has a value

```
var sharedServices = angular.module('sharedServices',[]);
sharedServices.value('currentFeed',{
'post': {}
 })
```

in this module which is in the header , i want to change the value according to my actions, in this case i am changing the value on clicking an li :

```
<li ng-click="changeFeed()"></li>

var navApp = angular.module('navApp',['sharedServices']);
navApp.controller('navController',['$scope','$http','$rootScope','currentFeed',function($scope,$http,$rootScope,currentFeed) {
    currentFeed.post = 'initial value';
    $scope.changeFeed = function() {
            currentFeed.post= 'changed value';
    });
}])
```

And this is the module , in which i want to show the changed value:

```
   var feedApp = angular.module('feedApp',['sharedServices']);
   feedApp.controller('FeedController',['$scope','currentFeed',function($scope,currentFeed) {
   $scope.currentFeed = currentFeed.post;
   }]);
```

but the value does not get updated as expected i guess :

```
       {{ currentFeed }} // this always remains 'initial value'
```

i cannot use $emit , $on as i dont have a common rootscope ..

how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should define one module and add to it others as dependency .
In that case you will have common $rootscope and then you can $broadcast or emit an event.

Comment: Not a fan of using events. I would prefer a **$watch** they don't want to use a getter function.

Comment: @Ashot how do i access a different module's rootscope in the controller

Comment: @Aakash when you define one module and add next 2 modules as dependency for it . You will have one module and one $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to bind a function in your **$scope** instead of a value.

```
$scope.currentFeed = currentFeed.post;
```

Becomes

```
$scope.getCurrentFeed = function() { return currentFeed.post; }
```

And you can use it from your template as a function (**getCurrentFeed()**)

Comment: this is not working , value is not changing in the view